# Socket.io multiple connections from one client

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a Node JS + Socket.io setup handling a chat + voting website. Since day one I've noticed, that from time to time there were multiple connections made from one client.

Client's browser (user agent) and network (ip) are different every time, and there is around 2-3k connections made at a time. This behavior is quite hard to diagnose/reproduce, since it happens once every couple days.

From what i've observed, it's like client's browser connects and immediately disconnects (times out), so it tries to reconnect. Socket.io doesn't know that user "timed out", so `io.engine.clientsCount` shows increased connections count for few minutes. This wouldn't be a problem, there is not much impact on performance, but it shows false data in stats, which is not acceptable for me.

As it shows on a screenshot below, this behavior causes "spikes" in connection counters:

[image: Graph]

I couldn't find any information about this behavior, but I had few ideas:

1. **Client is behind a firewall** - Node.JS listens on ports above 3000, so some public networks won't allow connections. This would be it, but then no connection would be made at all
2. **Client uses some kind of proxy** - But then I would get proxies IP address, instead of client's
3. **Possible DOS attack** - Nope. To simple, doesn't cause any damage.
4. **Installed plugin / disabled feature** - this could be possible, but I have no idea what would cause such a behavior.

Funny thing is, this behavior was observed with clients using relatively up-to-date browsers, so it's not like someone is trying his luck with IE4 :)

This is a real head-scratcher for me.. If anyone have observed something like this, i would really appreciate the help

**Edit 2016-02-07**

I caught 2 users with this issue and got some info about them:

```
HTTP headers:

host: ***.***.**.**:3000
connection: keep-alive
referer: http://***************.pl/
origin: http://***************.pl
x-wap-profile: http://wap.samsungmobile.com/uaprof/GT-P7510.xml
accept: text/xml, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, text/plain, */*;q=0.8
accept-charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.2; pl-pl; GT-P7510 Build/HTJ85B) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
accept-language: pl-PL, en-US
cookie: io=ejdnQT_TOXNpRc-GAJU8

Socket info:

time: Sun Feb 07 2016 17:13:05 GMT+0100 (CET)
address: ***.**.**.**
xdomain: true
secure: false
issued: 1454861585297
url: /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1454865217050-32520

-----

HTTP headers:

host: ***.***.**.**:3002
connection: keep-alive
referer: http://***************.pl/
origin: http://***************.pl
accept: text/xml, text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, text/plain, */*;q=0.8
accept-charset: utf-8, iso-8859-1, utf-16, *;q=0.7
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 3.2; pl-pl; GT-P7300 Build/HTJ85B) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/534.13
accept-encoding: gzip,deflate
accept-language: pl-PL, en-US
cookie: io=lLFL2chztf7gZzh3AFtG

Socket info:

time: Sun Feb 07 2016 17:40:55 GMT+0100 (CET)
address: **.***.*.**
xdomain: true
secure: false
issued: 1454863255162
url: /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1454863408365-11598
```

They both appear to be using Samsung tablets with Android 3.2. I've tested on Android AVD emulator with this version, but got no results.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just the long polling transport in action?

Comment: I've tested by adding `transports: ['polling']` on the client side and running `ab -n 100 -c 10 "http://192.168.1.30:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1450545297036-0"`. This does in fact create 100 new connections that drop after predefined timeout (around 60 sec?). However, described behavior is quite different. Connections seem to stack up at a rate just a bit higher than dropping. Besides, with polling transport there should still be just one connection (as observed in browser with `transports: ['polling']` option)

Comment: did you ever solve this? i have a similar behaviour. 150 clients, but 2500 connections.

Comment: Nope :( Project's already dead now, and I don't use anything similar for anything

Comment: @datayeah did you manage to figure this out -- I have the same. Polling requests only differ on `t` query param (yeast timestamp cachebusting).

Comment: @Nemesarial, to be honest, we switched the whole application back to classic HTTP requests & polling, since our application scales fast and we were not able to solve the problem. We also had problems with lots of clients having a bad internet connection and thus reconnecting to the socked more than 500 times a day. We didn't know if this could lead to performance issues when the application runs on multiple instances.

Comment: @datayeah I eventually did figure out our issue... When you use socket.io, it will default to using WebSocket as primary and polling as a fallback protocol. *But* the client first tries to connect using polling which will then upgrade to WebSocket. If you're making any socket messages before the upgrade is complete, it will just send them over regular long-polling requests. On upgrade to WebSocket, those other polling connections are disconnected and subsequent messages are emitted over the WebSocket connection.

To solve for us, I force use WebSocket only.

Comment: @Nemesarial yes, thats right, but unfortunately we have lots of clients that do not support websockets. But good to hear that it helped in your case :)